# Can't use protractor - spawn protractor ENOENT

Tags: angular, protractor, gulp-protractor

I want to run tests for a project, using Windows 10.
The tests spawn `protractor`, which errors:

> Error: spawn protractor ENOENT

I tried to do everything that might solve it, including:

- Adding `chromeOnly` to config
- Adding `directConnect` to config
- Adding `System32` to path
- Adding `JDK/.bin` and `JRE/.bin` to path

I still get this error when trying to spawn protractor.

Versions:

- Node: v6.9.1
- Protractor: v2.5.1 (also tried v5.1.1)

Source code: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/scripts/gulp/tasks/snapshot.ts#L80

Comment: not a lot of info here....how are you calling your protractor command...ENOENT typically means bad directory structure.

Comment: @LostJon Thanks, I added a link to the source code. It works on macs and linux machines

Comment: Why are you using v2.5.1 of Protractor?

Comment: @cnishina It is specified as what I need for this open source project. I tried using latest (5.1.1) without luck

Comment: seems windows is wonky...does this help at all https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3675

Comment: So it does not say install which Protractor to install. Looking at the @types/protractor, it requires ^4.0.0 but when installing it, the types are not downloaded and downloads 5.1.1.

Comment: @LostJon Thanks! The solution is to spawn `protractor.cmd` because windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For closing purposes. The issue was identified in  https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3675

because...windows.